# Drupal multi-language websites examples

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, multilingual

Please let me know if you have knowledge about some important sites that use Drupal CMS and have multi-language support. I know this is a job done using some google research but I really need a quick turnaround. I appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions about programming (i.e. writing code). You would be better served on [Web Applications.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) or [Pro Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.drupalsites.net is a nice site that lists drupal sites.

Here is a list of tags of sites made in drupal in all languages.

http://www.drupalsites.net/tagadelic/chunk/8

Comment: @user357314 did this this answer help you out ?

Answer (score 2):

How about http://fedex.com/